# How to get column names of a schema in sqlsoup in python?

Tags: python, mysql

How do you get column names and types in a dictionary from a schema/table using SQLSOUP in python? With MySQLDB I can create a cursor and use cursor.description. is there some equivalent for sqlsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#metadata-reflection):

> A Table object can be instructed to load information about itself from
>   the corresponding database schema object already existing within the
>   database. This process is called reflection. In the most simple case
>   you need only specify the table name, a MetaData object, and the
>   autoload=True flag. If the MetaData is not persistently bound, also
>   add the autoload_with argument:

```
>>> messages = Table('messages', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
>>> [c.name for c in messages.columns]
['message_id', 'message_name', 'date']
```

Comment: While correct, this is technically part of sqlalchemy and not part of the sqlsoup layer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that sqlsoup does have the ability to tell you the column names and types directly without going "underneath" to sqlalchemy. Table objects in sqlsoup have a member collection called 'c' that contains all the columns of the table, like so:

```
>>> import sqlsoup
>>> db =sqlsoup.SQLSoup('sqlite:///test.sqlite')
>>> db.example_table.c
<sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnCollection object at 0x1059819d0>
>>> db.example_table.c.keys()
[u'column_1', u'column_2', u'column_3']
>>> db.example_table.c['column_1']
Column(u'column_1', VARCHAR(), table=<example_table>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
>>> db.example_table.c['column_1'].type
VARCHAR()
```